# Most efficient way to read HTTP headers from a file?

Tags: go

I'm looking for an efficient way to read HTTP headers from a textfile to be later sent with an HTTP request. Consider the following code (which currently contains basic net/http request functionality):

```
func MakeRequest(target string, method string) {
client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, target, nil)

//Headers manually..
req.Header.Add("If-None-Match", `some value`)

response, _ := client.Do(req)
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

I started by using ioutil.ReadFile like this:

```
func main() {
data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/opt/tests/req.txt")
fmt.Print(string(data))
}
```

But taking this text, splitting it by some indicator (lets say ":") and then placing the information in req.Header.Add("var1", "var2") per-header seems like an over-kill.

**Question:** Any better way to send HTTP requests with headers from a text file in go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want some headers defined, another option is to define the headers in a Json file and apply the following code (file reading not included):

```
var jsonMap map[string]string
err = json.Unmarshal(jsonBytesFromFile, &jsonMap)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("unable to parse json: ", err)
}

for k, v := range jsonMap {
    log.Printf("setting Header : %s : %s", k, v)
    responseWriter.Header().Add(k, v) // you may prefer Set()
}
```

The json looks like this:

```
{ 
    "Content-type": "text/plain",
    "Cache-Control": "only-if-cached"
}
```

Comment: What is webRequest referrig to in your example? I can't seem to send a standard http.NewRequest in your way.

Comment: error: cannot call non-function req.Header (type http.Header)

Comment: nevermind, changed Header() to Header. worked. thanks!

Comment: @tatoe webRequest is the response writer you receive in the requesthandler func. Sorry, improved the naming.

Comment: @tatoe it is common to upvote helpful answers (hint)

Answer (score 3):

[net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http) has a method [ReadRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest) which can create a new `Request` object from a `bufio.Reader`. Assuming that your file contains a real HTTP request (instead of only the part of the request which consists of lines with `key: value`) all you need to do is create a new `bufio.Reader` from the file, i.e. like this (error handling omitted):

```
rdr,_ := os.Open("req.txt")
req,_ := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(rdr))
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", req)
```

Comment: Thank you, this returns <nil> . any idea why?

Comment: @tatoe: Does not return `<nil>` for me.  Maybe something is wrong with your request. I recommend that you check the errors which I've explicitly ignored to focus on the main idea. Note that the code expects a real  HTTP request which is not just some lines with `key: value`.

Comment: My bad, following your advice I noticed I forgot the appended newline after the request (thus got to unexpected EOF). thank you, you have provided me with a -very- efficient solution, was a smart idea to ask this before trying to implement the craziness I was about to :)